# Why webpack bundled as 'System.register'

Tags: angularjs, angular, webpack

I am trying develop a angular2 app using webpack, but it end up with an error in browser console say: Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined.

When I looked into the bundled js, I saw it is using System.register like below:

```
function(module, exports) {

    System.register(['angular2/platform/browser', './app.component'], function(exports_1) {
        var browser_1, app_component_1;
        return {
            setters:[
                function (browser_1_1) {
                    browser_1 = browser_1_1;
                },
                function (app_component_1_1) {
                    app_component_1 = app_component_1_1;
                }],
            execute: function() {
                browser_1.bootstrap(app_component_1.AppComponent);
            }
        }
    });
    // ...
```

My webpack.config.js is pretty simple as below:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: "./app/boot.ts",
    devtool: 'inline-sourcemap',

    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/dist",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader'}
        ]

    }
};
```

Can anyone fix for me? thanks.

Comment: If you're using webpack, you should transpile your code to `commonjs`. Go to your tsconfig.json file, and change `module` to `commonjs`.

Comment: Eric, you saved me. Could you please answer it, and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As suggested by @Ron

If you're using Webpack to bundle your application you must transpile your code to `commonjs`. The solution is to change `module` to `commonjs` in your tsconfig.json.

```
// tsconfig.json
"module" : "commonjs"
```

Here's a list of seed repositories for angular2 using webpack that can be helpful

- [ng2-webpack-play](https://github.com/pkozlowski-opensource/ng2-webpack-play) by @pkozlowski-opensource
- [angular2-webpack-starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) by @gdi2290
- [ng2-webpack](https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-webpack) by @ocombe

As an extra, I recommend you to watch [Modularity and Packaging for Angular2 Applications](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9odY9Rh5kTQ) by Pawel from AngularConnect2015

Comment: does not help for me